# how to transform data of two experimental groups? one is positively skewed and one is negatively..

Tags: anova, data-transformation, normalization, normality-assumption, skewness

I have two experimental groups. Then I test their normality respectively. Result shows that one is positively skewed and the other is negatively skewed. In this case, how should I do the data transformation? Can I log transform one group and reversed-log transform the other group？

Comment: The group size for each group is 50

Comment: What is the response? Some proportion? A Likert-scale? something else?

Comment: *Why* do you want to apply a transformation?  What analysis do you intend to do subsequently?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say on this little information, except that transforming different groups differently makes no sense and that mild skewness is often acceptable. Data that are exactly normal are probably fabricated!

It is possible that no transformation will help overall, or that one transformation will help overall. It's not just the sign of the skewness that is important but also its magnitude and why it arises.

If you could post the data, or graphs of them, you would be likely to get firmer advice.